# Siri shortcut fails to launch saying "The calendar is read only."

Tags: shortcut, apple-watch, siri

I've created a simple shortcut on my iPhone app that saves current date/time to reminders. It requires access to Location and Reminders. It works fine when I launch it on the iPhone (saying "Привет, Siri. Запусти %shortcut name%" - "Hello, Siri. Launch %shortcut name%"), but when I try the same thing on my Apple Watch it says "К сожалению, что-то пошло не так. The calendar is read only." - "Something went wrong. The calendar is read only". I don't understand why it seems to attempt modifying calendar data and what can I try to fix that?